# How can iterating a non-nullable Kotlin ArrayList with non-nullable elements produce NullPointerException?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a legacy Singleton `ItemsManager` which was created years ago.

```
    object ItemsManager {
        private var itemArrayList = ArrayList<Item>()

        // some other code...

    internal fun addItems(items: List<Item>) {
        if (items.isNotEmpty()) {
            itemArrayList.apply {
                clear()
                addAll(items)
            }
        }
    }

    internal fun updateItems(updatedItems: List<Items>) {
        updatedItems.forEach { updatedItem ->
            itemArrayList.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                if (item.id == updatedItem.id) {
                    itemArrayList[index] = updatedItem
            }
        }
    }

    internal fun getStockCount(): Int {
        val itemsListCopy = itemArrayList.clone() as? ArrayList<*>
        return itemsListCopy?.filterIsInstance<Items>()
            ?.filter { it.quantity > 0 }?.size ?: 0
    }
    }
```

There is a need to refactor this object and other closely related classes, but this is later work.
Currently, a known racing issue needs to be solved so the itemArrayList can be thread-safe, but it is not the concern of this post.

Here is the problem I cannot figure out now.

The itemArrayList is only accessible in this object file, no other files can modify or read it. All functions modify/read the itemArrayList have been provided above.

The app crashes at

```
if (item.id == updatedItem.id) {
```

with error,

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'java.lang.String
> com.example.auther.models.Item.getId()'

What I don't understand is that both updatedItems and itemArrayList and their elements are non-null, how can the line produce NullPointerException?

Could this be caused by the racing issue too?

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance

Edited:
The three functions can be called concurrently from a ViewModel,
like

```
addItems()
getStockCount()
```

or

```
updateItems()
getStockCount()
```

or

```
addItems()
updateItems()
```

Comment: Could you provide code fragments where `addItems()` and `updateItems()` are invoked? It looks they provided malformed list to one of these functions.

Comment: And you are correct: the problem may also happen due to running the code from multiple threads, e.g. invoking both functions in parallel or modifying the list of items passed to `updateItems()` concurrently.

Comment: Yeah, either of those could be the issue. Why not synchronize those functions? This class looks easy to make thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

I run your example but I dont get the error.

Maybe try something like

```
internal fun updateItems(updatedItems: List<Item>) {
    val itemArrayListTmp: MutableList<Item> = itemArrayList.toList().toMutableList()

    updatedItems.forEach { updatedItem ->
        itemArrayList.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            if (item.url == updatedItem.url) {
                itemArrayListTmp[index] = updatedItem
            }
        }
    }
    itemArrayList.clear()
    itemArrayList.addAll(itemArrayListTmp)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying it out. The three functions can be called concurrently from a ViewModel, so the current implementation has a concurrency issue for sure. Then there is also another error which is described in this post. But this NullPointerException error has only appeared once which means the issue doesn't appear often, some thing/conditions trigger it.

Comment: I believe you how is a good solution for what you are describing because addItems calls clear on the global array having the issue. Try a while loop to repro the error that call add and update repeatedly to trigger the error and see if this fixes it